# how to select a particular gcc-toolchain in clang?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, clang

Clang automatically selects the gcc-version with the highest version:

```
$ clang++ -v main.cpp
clang version 3.8.1-12 
(tags/RELEASE_381/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.4
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.1
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.0.1
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.4
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.1
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.0.1
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.0.1
```

how can i force clang to use a different gcc installation, say 5.4.1 ?

i tried to call clang with --gcc-toolchain="/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.1" but without success.

Comment: dupe (without an upvoted or accepted answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39218360/clang-gcc-toolchain-and-gcc-4-9-3-linking-issues

Comment: it look like you need  to build clang from source with  `--gcc-toolchain`

Comment: @bolov building clang with --gcc-toolchain wont enable me to pick the version i want (after compilation) nor is particularly practicable

Comment: agreed. I was just saying that the answer there indicate there is no way to specify it the way you want. And yeah, I am pretty disappointing if there really is no way of doing it (excluding workarounds).

Answer (score 16):

An valid path for --gcc-toolchain is apparently "/usr" as clang seem to look for gcc in

```
$PREFIX/{include|lib}/gcc/$PLATFORM/$VERSION/*
```

so as a workaround you can trick clang to use a particular version by creating a filesystem with overlay-fs or symlinking a folder-structure containing only one folder

```
mkdir $MYTOOLCHAIN
cd $MYTOOLCHAIN
ln -s /usr/include include #for headerfiles
ln -s /usr/bin bin #for tools like ld
mkdir -p lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/ #clang will deduce what to select
cd lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
#link the toolchain we want here
ln -s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/$VERSION $VERSION 
#usage: clang++ --gcc-toolchain=$MYTOOLCHAIN main.cpp
```

however maybe there is a better way by instructing clang to pick the version via a flag...

Comment: For clang 3.8 and older, make sure that $VERSION is the full version number. For instance, if /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.1 is a link to /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5, use "5.4.1", not "5". clang-3.9+ can deal with short toolchain versions.

Answer (score 5):

As of Clang-16, you can use --gcc-install-dir to simply pass the full path of the GCC installation.

Comment: Relevant documentation: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#:~:text=with%20%2Demit%2Dmodule-,%2D%2Dgcc%2Dinstall%2Ddir,-%3D%3Carg%3E%C2%B6