# "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++: No such file or directory" on running flutter linux app

Tags: ubuntu, clang++, flutter-linux

getting this error on `flutter run` for a linux desktop application

```
Running "flutter pub get" in proj...            5.3s
Launching lib/main.dart on Linux in debug mode...
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:62 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "/usr/bin/clang++"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /media/kingbob/Dvolve/EData/proj/build/linux/x64/debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/ninja cmTC_5f1b6 && [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_5f1b6.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
    [2/2] Linking CXX executable cmTC_5f1b6
    FAILED: cmTC_5f1b6 
    : && /usr/bin/clang++   CMakeFiles/cmTC_5f1b6.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -o cmTC_5f1b6   && :
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++: No such file or directory
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


Building Linux application...                                           
Exception: Unable to generate build files
```

output of flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.8, on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS 5.15.0-53-generic, locale en_IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

output of clang++ --version

```
Ubuntu clang version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

I noticed that `/usr/lib/libstdc++.so` was missing, so manually created a symlink
`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/lib/libstdc++.so`.

Then I ended up in this error on `flutter run`

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Linux in debug mode...
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/glib-typeof.h:39:10: fatal error: 'type_traits' file not found
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/glib-typeof.h:39:10: fatal error: 'type_traits' file not found
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/glib-typeof.h:39:10: fatal error: 'type_traits' file not found
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/glib-typeof.h:39:10: fatal error: 'type_traits' file not found
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/glib-typeof.h:39:10: fatal error: 'type_traits' file not found
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/glib-typeof.h:39:10: fatal error: 'type_traits' file not found
```

Answer (score 74):

I ran into a similar problem after a system upgrade. After a while, I realized that it was because `nvidia-driver-520-open` installed `gcc-12`. I use `clang-15` that I installed with the script [installClang15.sh](https://github.com/coveooss/clang-tidy-plugin-examples/blob/823d971a0f5e8c8d75697a3cd9e057778be3c885/installClang15.sh). `clang-15` depends and hence installs `libstdc++-11-dev` and `gcc-11`. The problem is that once `gcc-12` was installed, `clang++` picked it up automatically instead of `gcc-11`. This can be confirmed with `clang++ --verbose` which outputs something like

```bash
Ubuntu clang version 15.0.6
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12
Selected GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
```

### Solution 1: Install `libstdc++-12-dev`

I thought about this solution thanks to [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/115230#issuecomment-1312818514). This is the easiest solution, but it has a few drawbacks. On Ubuntu, you can install the package with

```bash
sudo apt install libstdc++-12-dev
```

The drawbacks that I faced are:

- I'd then be using a newer version of gcc (version 12). This might required (actually this *did* require) me to update my code. This is very problematic within the context of this question, where one doesn't necessarily control the code.
- What if in 6 months, `nvidia-driver-520-open` requires `gcc-13`? I would have to figure out again why I'm having this error, and then install `libstdc++-13-dev`, which might potentially require some code updates again.

### Solution 2: Fix the gcc installation that `clang++` uses

I did not find any clean and easy way to do that, but there are ways. `clang-16`, not yet released as of November 28th 2022 but available when [building clang](https://github.com/coveooss/clang-tidy-plugin-example#3-building-clang), has a new option `--gcc-install-dir` described [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html). This fixes compilation:

```bash
$HOME/src/llvm-project/staging/bin/clang++ --gcc-install-dir=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11 a.cpp
```

where `a.cpp` is a trivial C++ "Hello World!" program

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() { std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl; }
```

Older versions of `clang` have the option `--gcc-toolchain`, which is not quite as useful for reasons described [on llvm's discourse](https://discourse.llvm.org/t/add-gcc-install-dir-deprecate-gcc-toolchain-and-remove-gcc-install-prefix/65091). However, you can still be ingenious and do what [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41982109/3068259) suggest. The *TL;DR* is

```bash
sudo mkdir --parents /opt/gcc-root/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo ln --symbolic /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11 /opt/gcc-root/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11
sudo ln --symbolic /usr/include /opt/gcc-root/
```

The `ln --symbolic /usr/include /opt/gcc-root/` is important, otherwise I encountered problems with incremental build. Then, you should be able to compile with

```bash
clang++ --gcc-toolchain=/opt/gcc-root a.cpp
```

This leaves one question open: "How do I integrate this compiler option system wide?" I didn't find any satisfying answers here.

- You could use `export CCC_OVERRIDE_OPTIONS=^--gcc-toolchain=/opt/gcc-root` as described [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/cfe-commits@lists.llvm.org/msg207854.html) and documented [on GitHub](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/93a1fc2e18b452216be70f534da42f7702adbe1d/clang/tools/driver/driver.cpp#L79-L105). This might be the best solution within the context of this question.
- You could create a shell script named `clang++` that contains

  ```bash
  #!/usr/bin/env bash
  /usr/local/bin/clang++ --gcc-toolchain=/opt/gcc-root "$@"
  ```

  and then use `export CXX=<PATH_TO_SCRIPT>/clang++`. This work well enough in practice: it's been my quick and dirty fix. However, I'm worried that other tools in the toolchain (like `clang-tidy` or `clangd`) might have problems if they're not passed the option `--gcc-toolchain`. Depending on how you are setup, they might not see the option since it would not be in the file `compile_commands.json` created with the [`CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` CMake variable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.20/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html).
- You could use [clang's configuration files](https://releases.llvm.org/6.0.0/tools/clang/docs/UsersManual.html#configuration-files). The *TL;DR* is that you symbolically link `clang++` as, for instance, `fixed-gcc-root-clang++`, and then you create a file `fixed-gcc-root-clang++.cfg` in the proper place (for `clang-15`, it is `/usr/lib/llvm-15/bin`) that contains the option `--gcc-toolchain=/opt/gcc-root`. Finally, you use `export CXX=fixed-gcc-root-clang++`. A problem is that if somebody or something (for instance an IDE) uses `clang++` directly, your configuration file won't be read. You'll also have problems if a new symbolic link to `fixed-gcc-root-clang++` is created, for instance `c++ -> fixed-gcc-root-clang++`, since in this case, the configuration file would not be read.
- The best solution I found requires to control the build system, so it doesn't apply within the context of this question. The solution is to modify your build system toolchain. I find this unsatisfying since a packaging problem (remember, this is all because `nvidia-driver-520-open` installed a new transitive dependency) finds its solution in the C++ build system. Hence, [the separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principle is not respected.

Comment: Amazing comment! I would have never guessed that my nvidia driver could be the culprit. I'm seriously doubting ever installing an nvidia driver ever again because of all the issues I've had with them over the years.

Comment: `sudo apt install libstdc++-12-dev` work for me

Comment: @MattiaDinosaur For me as well. I'm still not entirely sure what the issue was:
Was it because clang automatically detects gnu toolchain's linker (ld) which in turn looks for an appropriate standardlibrary (libstdc++-12)?

Comment: This was driving me insane, thank you

Answer (score 12):

Install this:

Reinstall all dependencies (it is included here now)

```
sudo apt-get install clang cmake ninja-build pkg-config libgtk-3-dev liblzma-dev libstdc++-12-dev
```

You can read the last two entries here
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/115909

Comment: `sudo apt install libstdc++-12-dev`
fixed issue for me

Answer (score 1):

*Non-native speaker here. Apologies for any misunderstandings.*

**Install `libstdc++-12-dev`** will resolve this on Ubuntu 22.04 and derivatives.

```
sudo apt install libstdc++-12-dev
```

This is mainly because,

1. Ubuntu basically use gcc-11-based toolchain, so that `/usr/bin/gcc` is a symlink to `/usr/bin/gcc-11`.
2. The system-wide shared library is `libstdc++.so.6` compiled by gcc 12.3.0, which provided by `libstdc++6` package, the package depends on `gcc-12-base`.
3. *I think* because of **2.**, clang (`clang-14` by default) will search `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12` for shared lib rather than `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11` which `gcc-11` will do.

`ld` only treats `*.so` as shared lib, so `libstdc++.so.6` won't be queried by it. To include `libstdc++.so.6` into linker's search-path, `*-dev` packages need to create symlink from `*.so.6` to `*.so` under its path.

Package `libstdc++-11-dev` will put the symlink `libstdc++.so` under `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/` and `libstdc++-12-dev` will it under `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/`.

`clang` depends on `libstdc++-11-dev`, so only `libstdc++-11-dev` will be shipped with `clang` by default.

Cited from [How to print the ld(linker) search path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922949/how-to-print-the-ldlinker-search-path), `ld` search-path could be found as

```
$ /usr/bin/ld --verbose | grep SEARCH_DIR | tr -s ' ;' \\012
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
SEARCH_DIR("=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("=/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib")
```

, which do not contain any paths under `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu`.

Both gcc and clang passes a few extra -L paths to the linker, as

```
$ clang -print-search-dirs | sed '/^lib/b 1;d;:1;s,/[^/.][^/]*/\.\./,/,;t 1;s,:[^=]*=,:;,;s,;,;  ,g' | tr \; \\012
libraries:
  /usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/clang/14.0.0:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12:/usr/lib64:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/lib64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib64:/usr/lib/llvm-14/lib:/lib:/usr/lib
$ gcc-11 -print-search-dirs | sed '/^lib/b 1;d;:1;s,/[^/.][^/]*/\.\./,/,;t 1;s,:[^=]*=,:;,;s,;,;  ,g' | tr \; \\012
libraries:
  /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/:/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/:/usr/lib/:/lib/:/usr/lib/
$ gcc-12 -print-search-dirs | sed '/^lib/b 1;d;:1;s,/[^/.][^/]*/\.\./,/,;t 1;s,:[^=]*=,:;,;s,;,;  ,g' | tr \; \\012
libraries:
  /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/:/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/:/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/:/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/:/usr/lib/:/lib/:/usr/lib/
```

Only `gcc-11` (which is default on Ubuntu 22.04) passes `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/` to linker `ld`, so that only `gcc-11` (`/usr/bin/gcc` is a symlink to `/usr/bin/gcc-11` by default) will work.

As a result, installing `libstdc++-12-dev` will make `gcc-12` and `clang` available anyway. Also, it is workable to create a symlink `libstdc++.so` to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` under any path mentioned above.