# Ubuntu Upgrade caused flutter build to fail: Is it lstdc++ or gcc or Clang++?

Tags: flutter, gcc, cmake, clang++

After routine upgrade Ubuntu, my system build failed.
It is using gcc 14 now, and I guess it wants 13?

I tried following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74543715/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lstdc-no-such-file-or-directory-on-running-flutte/74556869?noredirect=1#comment131629650_74556869) but I don't know how to do syslink

Please give me a step by step answer of what to type.

The error-build output is below:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:62 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "/usr/bin/clang++"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /mnt/Data/git/tipitaka-pali-reader/build/linux/x64/release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/ninja cmTC_4da98 && [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_4da98.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
    [2/2] Linking CXX executable cmTC_4da98
    FAILED: cmTC_4da98 
    : && /usr/bin/clang++   CMakeFiles/cmTC_4da98.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -o cmTC_4da98   && :
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++: No such file or directory
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


Building Linux application...                                           
Unable to generate build files
```

The flutter doctor is below:

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.7, on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS 5.15.0-53-generic, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.73.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

I'm quite sure I need 13.  It is installed and reinstalled, but not showing below:

```
 $ clang++ --version
    Ubuntu clang version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1
    Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    Thread model: posix
    InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to upgrade or reinstall clang.

Comment: The problem is the upgrade itself.. I need to be able to force it to use 13.  Not sure how to do that.

Comment: Forget flutter. Can you compile a hello world c++ program with clang?

Comment: I found the problem and solved it.. yes.. need to fix for flutter.  I will post an answer.  It seems there is another unlisted dependency now needed.  I found the  github issue.

Answer (score 6):

It seems as though the new dependencies are not listed.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/115909

Reinstall all dependencies (it is included here now)

```
sudo apt-get install clang cmake ninja-build pkg-config libgtk-3-dev liblzma-dev libstdc++-12-dev
```